# How many different combinations are there for 3, 6 faced die where permutations don’t matter

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, dice

Say for each of the die, there are four faces showing “a”, one face showing “b” and one face showing “c”. How many different combinations can there be when there can be repeats (a,a,a) and permutations don’t matter (a,b,c = b,a,c)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The problem seems to be able to be done by enumerating the different cases, $a,a,a$; $a,a,b$; and so on, so perhaps you could attempt it and then ask if your solution is correct?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the dice don't seem to matter here. It only matters that they can show one of $3$ possible letters. That is, this seems to be no different from asking how many words one could form with $3$ letters. This seems like a suspiciously easy exercise with a suspicious amount of useless extra information.

Comment: I think you want the number of non-negative integer solutions to $a+b+c+d+e+f=3$ ($a$ = # 1's,...,$f$=#6's) which is same as # positive solutions to $A+B+C+D+E+F=9$ ($a=A-1$ etc.) which is $C(8,5)=56$ by the technique called "stars and bars" --in a row of $9$ stars, pick $5$ of the $8$ gaps to insert bars and then read off the values of $A$...$F$ by counting stars between bars.